# Why reference is pointing to an object of SCP area which is returned by concat() method in java?

Tags: java, string, heap-memory, immutability, pool

Tried running below code today -

```
     String s1 = new String("Hello");  
     String s2 = s1.concat("World"); 

     String s3 = s2.intern(); 
     System.out.println(s2 == s3); // returns true
```

As per my understanding, s2 should point to an object "HelloWorld" created in heap area. While s3 should point to its corresponding object present in SCP(String constant pool) area (new object which would be created in SCP due to intern() method call).

Why output is coming as 'true' then in this case? Is something happening behind the scenes here which I am not aware of?

Comment: `s2.intern()` can chose to put the objects referenced by `s2` itself into the pool (if no equal one is already in there) and then return that object. I.e. that object becomes part of the pool. And for quite some time now the string pool is no longer a "magical different place", it's members live in the heap like any other object.

Comment: And last but not least: it's not the "string constant pool", all manner of non-constant strings can end up in there (such as if you call `intern()` on a constructed string). Constants just happen to *also* be in there. Simply call it a "string pool".